# php hexdecimal conversion of png file

Tags: php, png

I am trying to get the image header from a png file. as the binary content show as neeble how can i show it as hexadecimal? i tried to base_convert() but it is not returning the desired output as i am getting the poutput in hexadecimel editor. any help will be appreciated.I am trying to do it with php

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but look at `unpack` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

Comment: can you tell what is the difference beetween low nibble first and high nibble first? which is the format described there as 'h' and 'H'

Comment: To be honest, I don't actually know the difference between the two, I have always just seen people use 'H' rather than 'h'

Comment: It is for nibble order - Show the first half of the byte or second half first. So "0xab" or "0xba".

Answer (score 0):

Try this for size:

```
$filename = "C:\\wamp\\www\\projects\\cog.png";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$binContents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

$hexContents = bin2hex($binContents);
echo $hexContents;
```